# JavaScript onclick event fired without any click

Tags: javascript, html, dom-events

I'm trying to clean the URLs of elements and every thing is working, but the `onclick` event fired directly on the page load but not when I click. How can I fix this?

HTML:

```
<a class="button" href="http://192.168.1.99:8888/propertyturkey/admin/clients/index/today_calls/?status=3&amp;sales=70&amp;tagged=1&amp;clientName=turkey&amp;nextCall=turkey&amp;clientEmail=sdfgsdfg">Today call list</a>
<input type="reset" class="reset" id="reset" value="Reset">
```

JS:

```
var buttons = document.querySelectorAll('.button');
var reset = document.querySelector('.reset');

function forEach(array, action) {
  for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    action(array[i])
  };
}

function clear_url_parameters(element) {

  if (!element)
    return false;
  var element_url = element.getAttribute('href');

  var split_url = element_url.split("?");

  var queries = split_url[1].split("&");

  var new_queries = [];

  for (var i = 0; i < queries.length; i++) {
    query = queries[i].split("=");
    new_queries.push(query[0] + "=");
  }

  cleared_url = split_url[0] + new_queries.join('');

  element.setAttribute('href', cleared_url);

}

reset.addEventListener('click', forEach(buttons, clear_url_parameters));
```

[Demo on jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sev2H/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are passing the result of executing the function `forEach` to your event listener.

Try this:

```
reset.addEventListener('click', function () { forEach(buttons, clear_url_parameters); } );
```

Answer (score 0):

change

```
reset.addEventListener('click', forEach(buttons, clear_url_parameters));
```

to

```
reset.addEventListener('click', function(){
    forEach(buttons, clear_url_parameters)
});
```

Because the parameter you  passed to `addEventListener` has already been called.

Comment: Thanks to your help and explanation, I really appreciate